# What do you call an endorsement of a person, not currently employed by some company, by a current employee of that company?

Tags: word-request

What do you call a formal (or, perhaps, informal) endorsement of a person, not currently employed by some company, by a current employee of that company? For some reason, I thought it's called a "referral", but I checked a few dictionaries, and it no longer seems so to me

Comment: You may be thinking of _reference_.

Comment: You could use "[referral](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/referral)", but "[refer](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/referring)" has a much more general meaning of "send or direct for treatment, aid, information, or decision", and applies to objects, ideas, decisions, etc, as well as people. A reference or recommendation are other words for formal or informal acts of endorsing someone.

Comment: @StuartF "reference" and "recommendation" seem to me too broad and generic

Comment: You could try asking it in https://workplace.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

The word you are looking for is **[reference](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/reference)**.
<sub>Definition B2</sub>

> a letter that is written by someone who knows you, to describe you and say if you are suitable for a job, course, etc.:
> "My old headteacher said he would write/give me a glowing (= very good) reference."

[Referral](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/referral), on the other hand, is

> the act of directing someone to a different place or person for information, help, or action often to a person or group with more knowledge or power:
> "The doctor gave him a referral to (= arranged for him to see) the consultant."

[Recommendation](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/recommendation) could be a generic term, but is not the one commonly used in the job market.

The thing about a 'reference' is it is not guaranteed to be positive, but can often be a formal/compulsory requirement in order to secure a new job.

Comment: This answer is misleading. You've confused the different uses of the word "reference". A reference can be something compulsorily required from a previous employer, which I suppose could be negative. But no person working for an organisation is going to 'refer' someone bad. They just wouldn't mention them.

Comment: @Astralbee - To the first part of your comment - no I haven't. If an employer asks for a reference & none is forthcoming, that's the same as a negative. Most HR departments send non-committal 'boiler-plate' letters unless someone was, for instance, dismissed for misconduct. The second part of your objection makes no sense. A reference doesn't come from just *anybody* in a company, it comes from HR, or suitable senior. If someone was just asking Bob from the post room, that's when 'recommendation' could be used, but not in formal circumstances.

Answer (score -1):

If the person being suggested for a position is known to the employee, you might call them a *recommendation* or a *referral*.

Although both these words refer to the act of making such a suggestion, it is common to use these to refer to the person being recommended or referred.

For example:

- I made a recommendation of [name].
- [Name] was a recommendation.#

[Webster's dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/referral) makes the same distinction:

> re·​fer·​ral
> 1
> : the act, action, or an instance of referring
> gave the patient a referral to a specialist
> 2
> : one that is referred

Comment: Recommendation could work, though it is not the word commonly used in the job market. Referral is just wrong.

Comment: @Tetsujin It *is* the word I use in my experience as an employer, and as you can see from my reference, the dictionary agrees.

Comment: The dictionary disagrees. You even copied it out for me to see it disagrees.